# Use No-Sql with EF

Tags: mongodb, entity-framework, ravendb, nosql

I want to use  No-Sql in my application I think [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/) and MongoDb are good but which one is more integrated with EF?
and is there any documentation for using theme?

Comment: Neither fit. Both have their own unique APIs and access patterns.  List of supported relational databases is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure why this is closed, I feel the question asked is valid regardless of the answer. I don't feel that this is an opinion based or polling question perhaps the wording needs a little adjustment?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Clearly if you look in the comments of the answer you gave, *including your own comments*, this is clearly opinion-based and not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.  StackOverflow is primarily for coding questions.  It was closed appropriately.

Comment: @MattJohnson my feeling is that there is perhaps 2 questions here, 'Can you use EF with no-sql databases' and 'whats the best framework to use to connect to no-sql databases'. The first is valid the second is polling. The first was the question i answered, the second was discussed in comments. Regardless it appears its not really worth the effort to reopen here so im going to leave it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework is built to support relational databases. It has no support for any no-sql or document databases. And when you think about it, it actually doesn't make too much sense, what is the point of using an object relational mapper and producing a relational mapping of a non-relational database?

There are however libraries which support both of these frameworks available for .Net available via nuget. Im sure these would be much more appropriate for your application

Comment: What is your opinion about big data and using nosql in .Net

Comment: In my opinion document databases have an important place to play with specific datasets. They generally scale a lot better that traditional relational datasources. But for that scale you pay with some of the assumptions you can make with relational databases. In terms of BigData, most of the really big datasources seem to be using non-relational storage. CF Facebook google ect...

Comment: Interestingly enough I think stack overflow to spite the current volume of data they process use mssql and a redis cache for their storage and they care a lot about performance and Scaling. So your data set needs to be very large before you stop being able to use relational data storage. That being said there are other good reasons to use non-relational storage other than scale. If your data isn't relational why force it to be?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor EF7 might https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1035